# Circle image crop when using UIImagePickerController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to crop images circle when importing from photo library, just like in the stock contacts app. I found a few solutions but all of them were in Objective-C. I found them hard to translate. Does anyone know a useful swift library or so?

Comment: may be this can be helpful for someone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53248609/how-to-crop-image-in-circle-shape-with-grid-inside-circle?noredirect=1#comment93384821_53248609

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
    profileImage.image = UIImageVar
    profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
    profileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.frame.height/2
    profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Yeah but the main point is to get that editor view when you see a dark something with a "hole" in it and you can crop the image

Answer (score -1):

If you're seeking something like Core Graphics, you can take the following for references.

```
let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
let image = UIImage(named: "YourImageName")!

// Oval Drawing
let width = image.size.width
let height = image.size.height
let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
ovalPath.addClip()
image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
```

Comment: Did you even read the question, OP asks for how to do it like in the stock contacts app.